# Visibility of field only when particular field selected

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have a selection field and another many2one field in odoo10. And i want that when i select only "service" from selection type field then another many2one field visible on the form view. Here i attach my python and xml code.

Python code:-

```
service_types = fields.Selection([('product', ('Product')),('service', ('Service'))], string='Services', required=True),
name_rental = fields.Many2one('rental.pet', string="Rental Management")
```

Xml code:-

```
<field name="service_types"/>
<field name="name_rental" attrs="{'invisible': [('service_types', '!=', 'service')]}"/>
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, to me.  What problems are you seeing?

Comment: Yes it's work, but can you tell me that how can i show complete form(rental.pet) in wizard when select 'service' option.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this format**

**Fields used: Selction and Many2one record**

when I select only "service" from selection type field then another many2one field visible on the form view.

**Python Code:**

**ODOO10**

```
service_types = fields.Selection(([ ('product', 'Product'), ('service', 'Service')]), string='Services',required=True)
name_rental = fields.Many2one('rental.pet', string="Rental Management")
```

**XML Code:**

```
<field name="service_types"/>
<field name="name_rental" attrs="{'invisible': [('service_types', '!=', 'service')]}"/>
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work, check that you have declared the .xml and .py

Comment: Yes it's work, but can you tell me that how can i show complete form(rental.pet) in wizard when select 'service' option.